# jQuery: retain default selection after sorting <option>s in <select> filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, drop-down-menu

Magento's admin Product Grid has `<select>` filters for searching products.
Some of those are notoriously unsorted (ie. attribute_sets).

Because I keep discovering this unsorted behaviour in too many locations to fix on the php side, I'd like to use a js approach to fix it.

I got the sorting part finished, that part is done.

But after `.append()`ing the resulting set back the pull down menu loses the previously `selected` option. (ie. the filter that was used to load the grid)

I'm missing something basic, but I don't know what.

Here's my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpalasis/3erszvzf/29/)

*Cleaner code w/o my debug msgs [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpalasis/8rex19t1/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like I said, it was something basic... I don't know why I could not figure it out yesterday, but anywho:

before sorting:

```
var whichSelectedVal = $(elid).val(); // stores the current option
```

after sorting:

```
$(elid).val(whichSelectedVal); // re-selects the stored option
```

This works even for the blank filter option, yay for me, no extra work needed to account for that ;)